# Scheduled execution of a shell script returning incorrect value (script execution is scheduled with cron) (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a shell script which is scheduled to run every minute using a crontab entry.
The script checks if the Java process is up. If the process is not up, it will try to bring up the Java process

Below is the shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
val=0
val=$(ps -efa | grep -v grep | grep import -c)
echo ${val} >> /software/deployment/service/import2/import-integrator.log
if [[ ${val} -eq 4 ]]; then echo "Import Up" >> /tmp/output.log
else
echo "Import Down" >> /tmp/output.log
cd /software/deployment/service/import2/
nohup /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar -Xms4096m -Xmx16384m /software/deployment/service/import2/import-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war >> /software/deployment/service/import2/import-integrator.log &
echo "Import Started" >> /tmp/output.log
fi
```

The above script is schedule using below command (using **root** user account)

```
crontab -e
```

Below is the entry

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /software/deployment/service/import2/restart_import.sh
```

The problem is that the value of **val** variable is coming as **4** ***(count of matching pattern by grep)*** if the process is up and it is coming as **3** if the process is down. **This happens when the script is executed automatically by cron**

**val** is evaluated as below

```
val=$(ps -efa | grep -v grep | grep import -c)
```

If the script is executed manually, the value of **val** is **1** when the process is up and it is **0** when the process is down.

I want to understand why this is happening (execution of same command manually and via cron returning two different values)

Comment: what do you see with ```ps -efa | grep -v grep | grep import``` when the process
is
running with cron? you are writing to logs files and those may appear in the ```ps``` output and hence it increases the total match for ```import```. A better way to detect whether the file (war file) is 'up' is to use the ```fuser``` command. ```fuser software/deployment/service/import2/import-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war```

Comment: When running ps -efa | grep -v grep | grep import, I can see a single process running (containing 'import' at two places in the path of the process.

Comment: i see. I would run that command  from cron and redirect the output to a file
and see what are those extra matches.
You can give that a try

Answer (score 0):

Following the logic of your script with cron:

#### minute 1

Assuming `${val}` == 0

Script runs:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar -Xms4096m -Xmx16384m /software/deployment/service/import2/import-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war >> /software/deployment/service/import2/import-integrator.log &
```

#### minute 2

Assuming `${val}` == 1

Script runs:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar -Xms4096m -Xmx16384m /software/deployment/service/import2/import-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war >> /software/deployment/service/import2/import-integrator.log &
```

#### minute 3

Assuming `${val}` == 2

Script runs:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar -Xms4096m -Xmx16384m /software/deployment/service/import2/import-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war >> /software/deployment/service/import2/import-integrator.log &
```

#### minute 4

Assuming `${val}` == 3

Script runs:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar -Xms4096m -Xmx16384m /software/deployment/service/import2/import-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war >> /software/deployment/service/import2/import-integrator.log &
```

#### minute 5

Assuming `${val}` == 4

Script runs:

```
echo "Import Up" >> /tmp/output.log
```

#### minute 6

Assuming `${val}` == 4

Script runs:

```
echo "Import Up" >> /tmp/output.log
```